# AngularJS throwing syntax parse error when using expression as a parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

I'm getting an error when trying to parse this markup, basically I need to use an expression as a parameter of the function in the `ng-click`, but it's not letting me. If I don't use an expression then the src in the `img src="{{image.media.m}}" ng-model="image.media.m"` will get cleared when clicking on the album `img` causing the image to disappear. This error causes my `saveToAlbum` function to not work the way it should..

What would be the proper way of writing this I wonder? And why exactly isn't this allowed?

```
<ul class="images-list">
    <li ng-repeat="image in imageGroup" ng-controller="albumsCtrl">
        <img src="{{image.media.m}}" ng-model="image.media.m">
        <div class="topDiv">
            <img src="img/album.png" ng-click="saveToAlbum({{image.media.m}}, undefined)">
        </div>
        <div class="bottomDiv" ng-controller="favoritesCtrl">
            <img src="img/favorites.png" ng-click="addToFavorites(image.media.m)">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=14&p3=saveToAlbum(%7B%7Bimage.media.m%7D%7D%2C%20undefined)&p4=%7Bimage.media.m%7D%7D%2C%20undefined)
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:6:417
at hb.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:190:254)
at hb.object (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:199:435)
at hb.primary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:189:308)
at hb.unary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:197:82)
at hb.multiplicative (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:196:324)
at hb.additive (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:196:182)
at hb.relational (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:196:48)
at hb.equality (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:195:418) <img src="img/album.png" ng-click="saveToAlbum({{image.media.m}}, undefined)">
```

Comment: `saveToAlbum({{image.media.m}}, undefined)` should be `saveToAlbum(image.media.m, undefined)`

Comment: use ngSrc for the src='' and loose the {{}} i the saveToAlbum function.

Comment: @Chandermani I explained why it shouldn't though.

Comment: @satchcoder It's ng-src not ngSrc though, but that did the trick. Post as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz ngSrc is the normalized name of the directive. You can then use `data-ng-src` or `ng-src`. @satchcoder are you sure `{{}}` can be omitted? My code seems to still require them even in `ngSrc`

Comment: @MKSafi You can't omitt the brackets unless you use ng-src. When using ngSrc nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use ng-src for the src='' and loose the {{}} i the saveToAlbum function